# Reading from a text file in swift and dealing with white space

Tags: arrays, swift, file-io

I'm learning Swift and I'd just like to know the best way to go about reading in a text file, breaking it up into lines and then taking each word on each line and turn the words into strings that can be loaded into class initialisers.

For example, if I have this text file:

```
**This is just a random text file, and the text on this line
and this line is not needed**
birth year    birth month   birth day     favourite colour
1990          11            12            red
1995           2             4            pink 
1992           5             3            orange
1987           3            19            blue
```

I want to take the birth year, birth month, birth day and favourite colour from each line and then load it into a class like this:

```
Person(birthYear: 1990, birthMonth: 11, birthDay: 12, favouriteColour: red)
```

The text file that I want to read in might have an uneven amount of spaces so the output will look like this (for the given text file):

```
["**This", "is", "just", "a", "random", "text", "file,", "and", "the", "text", "on", "this", "line"]
["and", "this", "line", "is", "not", "needed**"]
["birth", "year", "", "", "", "birth", "month", "", "", "birth", "day", "", "", "", "", "favourite", "colour"]
["1990", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "11", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "12", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "red"]
["1995", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "4", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "pink", ""]
["1992", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "5", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "3", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "orange"]
["1987", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "3", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "19", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "blue"]
```

Here is my code so far:

```
let path = "path to my file"

    if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {

        // breaking the text file up into lines
        let lines = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n")

        // breaking the lines up into wordsw
        for line in lines {
            let elements = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
            print(elements)
        }

    }
```

I'm just wondering what the best way to deal with white space in these cases would be.  Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: You probably should save your files in a CSV kind of format. Normal texts are not suited to automate definition of their semantics, unless you really want to dive deep into AI or you know that your files will look exactly the same (but from the question it rather sounds like it isn't the case)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I'll keep this in mind.  I managed to get the information I wanted from the txt file by separating each line into its own array, filtering out the white space so I was left with  something like this for each line:
 [1995,  2 , 4, "pink"].  Then I just stored these values for each line in a variable like year = Int(myarray[0]) and passed it to my class to then appended each object to another array.  It's a bit messy but it works! Just posting in case someone else is looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple solution to clean all Tabs and Double spaces. Try use this piece of code.

```
func cleanTabsAndSpace(in text:String) -> String {
    var newText = text
    newText = newText.filter{ $0 != "\t" }.reduce(""){ str, char in
        if let lastChar = str.last, lastChar == " " && lastChar == char {
            return str
        }
        return str + String(char)
    }

    return newText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
```

After create this function you can call it inside your function

```
if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {

    // Clean undesired chars
    let cleanContent = cleanTabsAndSpace(in: contents)

    // breaking the text file up into lines
    let lines = cleanContent.components(separatedBy: "\n")

    // breaking the lines up into wordsw
    for line in lines {
        let elements = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
        print(elements)
    }

}
```

With this you will have all your content separated as you wish. Now you have just to follow as you want, parsing the content as you want and create your objects.

I'm just considering this structure you described in your question.

Good luck friend and Feel free to contact me if you need something more.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  This is a lot cleaner than the solution I found myself.

Comment: Hi @dede.exe, is there a simple way to do this for multiple files?  For example if I had the file from the OP and another file, could I load both in and create one big array of objects with the contents from both files?  **This is just a random text file, and the text on this line
and this line is not needed**
birth year    birth month   birth day     favourite colour
1992          10            9            black
1993           1             2            white 
1994           3             1            brown c

Comment: Yes @cminusminus, you can... All you have to do is concatenate all files in a single string, but if you have a lots of files, I think you create a loop, process the file and merge the final result in the array. It's a better solution than read all files and concatenate in a colossal string.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`split(separator:maxSplits:omittingEmptySubsequences:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2908109-split)
method which allows to split a `String`
into an array of `SubString`s.

In contrast to `components(separatedBy:)` this method (by default) 
omits empty substrings caused by consecutive separator characters.

Example:

```
let line = "1990          11            12            red"
let elements = line.split(separator: " ")
print(elements) // ["1990", "11", "12", "red"]
```

Here `element` has the type `[SubString]`, i.e. the substrings reference
the original character storage in `line`, without duplicating it.

If you need "real" strings, then change it to

```
let elements = line.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)
```

Applied to your case:

```
if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) {
    let lines = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    for line in lines {
        let elements = line.split(separator: " ")
        print(elements)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin.  I wasn't aware of the different methods I could call to help with sorting, Swift is a really fun language to learn!

Comment: @Martin R, what if i can not read the file for special character ? content return ""

Comment: @JamshedAlam: `String(contentsOfFile:)` has no problems with special characters, but expects the file to be UTF-8 encoded. If your file uses a different encoding then you have to use `String(contentsOfFile:, encoding:` with the correct encoding, (for example `.isoLatin1`).